# Error while adding project

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'm trying to create a new solution with dot net nuke.

I installed the packages and configured IIS to work with it.

Then with visual studio i created a new solution. I want to import an old module already created, so i copied/pasted the folder in "DesktopModules".

Then with VS i right click on the solution and selects add existing project.

This way i get an error:
The web application project "name" is configured to use IIS. The web server "http://dnndev.me/desktopmodules/name" is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the corresponding projet is configured to use a web server depending on the URL you've got.
I suggest you to edit the project file with notepad (csproj or vbproj) and to remove the specified URL configuration. You also have to set the UseIIS value to false.
Note that this configuration could be stored in the users project file (.vbproj.user or .csproj.user).
Then, try again to add this project to your solution.